# How to handle changed facebook and expired token in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, facebook-graph-api

I am developing my mobile app in flutter with Facebook Login with https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth.

I am trying to handle expired token but don't know how.

I am getting error from GraphApi when I am trying to do:

```
Future<Map> getUserInformation() async {
    return await facebook.getUserData(
        fields:
            'id,name,email,picture.width(600),friends');
  }
```

and this is error:

```
{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: 460, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.}
```

How to catch and handle it?

Comment: Hii @Karol I am facing the same issue in production. What I did is I always calls an API when my app starts which basically fetches the data, basic user profile. if it returns false status (status other than 200...300). I simply Navigate back to Login Screen again by using the navigation key (For navigation Without Context from network layer).

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma can you send example code how you catching status code from graphApi?

Comment: I really wish I never even added Facebook Auth.  It's the worst.